# Render nested routes as individual pages in VueJS

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-router

I'm using VueJS's own router component. In my admin interface, there is one page which shows an overview list and another one with specific options for one single entry.

```js
function configRoutes() {
    return [
        {
            path: '/',
            redirect: '/default',
            name: 'Home',
            component: TheContainer,
            children: [
                {
                    path: 'admin/viewerRoles',
                    name: 'List',
                    component: AdminViewerRoles,
                    children: [
                        {
                            path: ':id-:name',
                            name: 'Settings',
                            component: AdminViewerRoleSettings
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

With that approach, I can place a `<router-view />` tag in my AdminViewerRoles component. This will render the details page as viewport. What I wonder is, if it is possible to render either of the views without giving up the syntactically correct, nested navigation approach.

My idea would be to place the `<router-view />` tag and the normal page content in two different `div` elements and render them conditionally with `v-if`. But is that really the best approach?

This would be my idea (untested):

```html
<template>
  <div v-if="$route.params.id">
    <router-view />
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    <table>...</table>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Do you want to render either `AdminViewerRoles` or `AdminViewerRoleSettings` ?

Comment: @ShivamSingh Yes. But in CoreUIs navigation breadcrumb, they should still appear as nested routes.